# Play framework url problems

Tags: jquery, scala, playframework, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm implementing [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in my PlayFramework application. But my current code returns 404 error.

My code in `index.scala.html`:

```
<script>
       $( function() {
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: "jsRoutes.controllers.BasicController.auto"
            } );
        } );
</script>
<input id="search">
```

`BasicController`'s method `auto` returns JSON response formatted like:

```
[{"label":"label1","value":"value1"},{"label":"label2","value":"value2"}]
```

`routes` file:

```
GET     /auto                       controllers.BasicController.auto(term: String)
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
GET     /javascriptRoutes           controllers.BasicController.javascriptRoutes
```

Javascript Router is set according to [official Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting). It seems to me that problem is in the `source` parameter of `.autocomplete` function. Maybe the *URL* should look the other way?

#### Edit:

Router method

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(
        JavaScriptReverseRouter("jsRoutes")(
            routes.javascript.BasicController.auto
        )
    ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

And in template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.BasicController.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

Comment: How are you generating the router? Embedded or Action? Can you paste your router code?

Comment: @Nio , added the code.

Comment: @АндрейЮсупов Try to use `jsRoutes.controllers.BasicController.auto().url` instead

Comment: @Salem ,  source: jsRoutes.controllers.BasicController.auto().url doesn't work at all, even no requests are sent.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
 source: "@routes.BasicController.auto()"
```

So I misunderstand why are `jsRoutes` needed(as said in official documentation).